# Compare Child Nodes with Elements in XQuery

Tags: sql, sql-server, xquery, sqlxml, xquery-sql

I am trying to see if an xml document in sql meets certain requirements.

```
CREATE TABLE #ValueExample
(
XMLDocument xml
)

INSERT INTO #ValueExample
VALUES ('<History>
  <step start="2/22/2015 5:17:55 PM" end="" user="Intake Processor">
    <type id="1" value="2" />
    <type id="2" value="0" />
    <type id="3" value="0" />
    <type id="4" value="0" />
  </step>
  <step start="2015-03-13 10:56:29.980" end="" user="BD Save Followup">
    <type id="0" value="5" />
    <type id="1" value="4" />
    <type id="2" value="3" />
    <type id="3" value="0" />
    <type id="4" value="0" />
  </step>
  <step start="2015-02-22 20:08:58.053" end="" user="BD Save Followup">
    <type id="0" value="5" />
    <type id="1" value="4" />
    <type id="2" value="174" />
    <type id="3" value="181" />
    <type id="4" value="0" />
  </step>
</History>')
```

I need to know if this document has a step node that has the 
 child elements of type with attribute values of id = 2 and value = 174, 
 also a type element with the attributes of type id = 3 and value = 181.

Basically, the last node meets my conditions. here is the sql I have tried, along with a way to create a test.

Sql I am trying

```
SELECT c.query('.') AS XMLFragment
,c.value('(@id)[1]','int') AS value
,c.query('..') as wholexml
,c.value('(@id)[1]','int') as id
,c.value('(@value)[1]','int') as value
,c.query('(//step/type)[1]') as typeelements
FROM #ValueExample
CROSS APPLY XMLDocument.nodes('//step/type') as t(c)
```

the problem is I need the last one typeelements, grouped by steps...

I hope this was clear enough to understand. If you need additional clarifiation, just ask.

Answer (score 0):

you can use sqlxml [`exist()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189869.aspx) method

```
select
    t.c.query('.') AS XMLFragment
from #ValueExample as v
    cross apply v.XMLDocument.nodes('//step') as t(c)
where
    t.c.exist('type[@id=2 and @value=174]') = 1 and
    t.c.exist('type[@id=3 and @value=181]') = 1
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb/4130)</kbd>**